# Can't fit UIImage inside UIScrollview

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiimage

I'm using this code to pick an image from gallery and fit it inside a `UIScrollView`:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: inputImageDelegate!)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentView.frame.width, height: contentView.frame.height)
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
inputImage = imageView
contentView.addSubview(imageView)

self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.inputImage.frame.size

self.scrollView.delegate = self
self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1
imageView.sizeToFit()
```

Result:
[image]

I want to make image's width equal to the screen width after loading (user can scale it up and down). Neither of `self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1` nor `imageView.sizeToFit()` worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have your scroll view connected to an `IBOutlet` like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
```

You should set the `frame` of the `UIImageView` based on the `UIScrollView`'s `contentSize` property.

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: inputImageDelegate!)
let contentSize = self.scrollView.contentSize // convenience
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentSize.width, height: contentSize.height)
...
```